# Is bootloader code linked to any other Software?

Tags: boot, boot-loader, angstrom

I want to use DAS U-boot and a form of embedded Linux.

Is bootloader code linked in any way to other source code (e.g. statically, dynamically)?

Or is it standalone?

Answer (score 1):

**It is 'stand alone'.**

The bootloader will init the board and load the OS, linux in your case.
The boot loader must be compiled for your board and specific setup, memory (sdram), storage (nand or mmc).

It is possible to 'do work' only in u-boot. Partition mmc flash the NAND etc.

Some vocabulary to help you in your search:

bare metal

cross compile

device tree

Comment: Correct, (most) boards use something similar to a BIOS (but simpler).  Something like UEFI (which may use the same kernel to load the kernel into memory) is pretty much unheard off in embedded.